# How use Vue.set() in NuxtJs application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to set a property, by using Vue.set() in Nuxtjs application.

```
editPost(post) {
    Vue.$set(post, 'edit', true)
}
```

Got error: *Vue is not defined*

Comment: `import Vue from 'vue'` at the top of `script`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use `this` instead of `Vue.`. This references the current vue component inside the method, so it will work same way:

```
editPost(post) {
    this.$set(post, 'edit', true)
}
```

Comment: @DrewBaker in store you can use Vue.set

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend(). However, new properties added to the object will not trigger changes. In such cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original object and the mixin object:

// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })